# Ubuntu apt-get install -f fails because package on server is newer then repo

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

Not sure exactly what to do with this. Error Below.

From what I can tell, somehow I got a package on the system which is newer then it expects and because of that it borks, and the other packages want to have an older version.  Chances are they are compatible but it does not like it.

What I can do?  I need to install packages unrelated to this on the system.

```
apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  initramfs-tools libc6-dev
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  initramfs-tools libc6-dev
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1292 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,955 kB of archives.
After this operation, 553 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-bin (<< 0.99ubuntu13.1~); however:
  Version of initramfs-tools-bin on system is 0.103ubuntu4.2.
 klibc-utils (2.0.3-0ubuntu1) breaks initramfs-tools (<< 0.103) and is installed.
  Version of initramfs-tools to be configured is 0.99ubuntu13.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
 udev depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.92bubuntu63); however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing udev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth:
 plymouth depends on udev (>= 166-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
 plymouth depends on initramfs-tools; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing plymouth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mountall:
 mountall depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
 mountall depends on plymouth; however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                   dpkg: error processing mountall (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initscripts:
 initscripts depends on mountall (>= 2.28); however:
  Package mountall is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upstart:
 upstart depends on initscripts; however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package initscripts is not configured yet.
 upstart depends on mountall; however:
  Package mountall is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing upstart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of passwd:
 passwd depends on upstart-job; however:
  Package upstart-job is not installed.
  Package upstart which provides upstart-job is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing passwd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dmsetup:
 dmsetup depends on initramfs-tools; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
 dmsetup depends on udev (>> 141-2); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dmsetup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cron:
 cron depends on upstart-job; however:
  Package upstart-job is not installed.
  Package upstart which provides upstart-job is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing cron (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbus:
 dbus depends on upstart-job; however:
  Package upstart-job is not installed.
  Package upstart which provides upstart-job is not configured yet.
 dbus depends on upstart (>= 0.6.3-6); however:
  Package upstart is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dbus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of accountsservice:
 accountsservice depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing accountsservice (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbus-x11:
 dbus-x11 depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dbus-x11 (--configure):No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of policykit-1:
 policykit-1 depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing policykit-1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of policykit-1-gnome:
 policykit-1-gnome depends on policykit-1; however:
  Package policykit-1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing policykit-1-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnm-gtk0:
 libnm-gtk0 depends on policykit-1-gnome; however:
  Package policykit-1-gnome is not configured yet.
 libnm-gtk0 depends on dbus-x11; however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libnm-gtk0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-system-service:
 ubuntu-system-service depends on policykit-1; however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package policykit-1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-system-service (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-control-center:
 gnome-control-center depends on libnm-gtk0; however:
  Package libnm-gtk0 is not configured yet.
 gnome-control-center depends on accountsservice; however:
  Package accountsservice is not configured yet.
 gnome-control-center depends on ubuntu-system-service (>= 0.1.10); however:
  Package ubuntu-system-service is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gnome-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dev:
 libc6-dev depends on libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.5); however:
  Version of libc6 on system is 2.19-0ubuntu6.
 libc6-dev depends on libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.5); however:
  Version of libc-dev-bin on system is 2.19-0ubuntu6.
dpkg: error processing libc6-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-label:
 plymouth-label depends on plymouth (= 0.8.2-2ubuntu31.1); however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package plymouth is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing plymouth-label (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox:
 rhythmbox depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing rhythmbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder:
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist:
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (>= 2.96-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (<< 2.97); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-mozilla:
 rhythmbox-mozilla depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-mozilla (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune:
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins:
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.3); however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugins (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core:
 xserver-xorg-core depends on udev (>= 149); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing xserver-xorg-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdevmapper1.02.1:
 libdevmapper1.02.1 depends on dmsetup (>= 2:1.02.48-4ubuntu7.3); however:
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                Package dmsetup is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libdevmapper1.02.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 udev
 plymouth
 mountall
 initscripts
 upstart
 passwd
 dmsetup
 cron
 dbus
 accountsservice
 dbus-x11
 policykit-1
 policykit-1-gnome
 libnm-gtk0
 ubuntu-system-service
 gnome-control-center
 libc6-dev
 plymouth-label
 rhythmbox
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
 rhythmbox-mozilla
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
 rhythmbox-plugins
 xserver-xorg-core
 libdevmapper1.02.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I would post the sources.list but I do not have the reputation and it complains

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
```

## deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

# deb http://dl.hiphop-php.com/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe      multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: If you use code formatting for sources.list it will not complain about reputation. Note that you may also ask at [ubuntu.SE] if this cannot be answered here.

Comment: Have you run `apt-get dist-upgrade` yet?

Comment: I am actually wanting to run that command but it says to run this one I am asking the question about apt-get install -f.  Says unmet dependencies with some of the packages in the error message above.. initramfs-tools, klibc-utils, libc6-dev etc.